# Getter/Setter does not seem to work

Tags: javascript, windows, ecmascript-6, phonegap

In my class when I try to make a getter or a setter I get this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: item.name is not a function
```

My code is this

```
class Item {
    constructor(n) {this._name = n};
    get name() {return this._name};
}

var x = new Item('test')
var newItem = 'New Item: '+x.name()
```

Comment: x.name() -> x.name because name is a getter.

Comment: If you really want to use as a method, then remove `get` keyword.

Comment: Thank you very much! It actually worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getters and Setters will create a pseudo-property with their respective name for the object created by your Class. 
Thus you can control them without calling them like a function. For Getters:

```js
class Item {
    constructor(n) {this._name = n};
    get name() {return this._name};
}

var x = new Item('test')
var newItem = 'New Item: '+x.name

console.log(newItem);
```

And for Setters:

```js
class Item {
    constructor(n) {this._name = n};
    get name() {return this._name};
    set name(n) {this._name = n};
}

var x = new Item('test')

x.name = "foo";

var newItem = 'New Item: '+x.name

console.log(newItem);
```

Read more about this [at MDN's guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters)

Answer (score 0):

Get and set method calling should not need () the caller.You can directly call them as

```
x.name
```

Comment: I didn't even think of that!Thank you very much

Comment: Pleasure!! please up vote if the you are satisfied with answer